# touchesEnd not the same as UIControlEventTouchUpInside

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do i pass an event from a subview to trigger UIControlEventTouchUpInside of its superview(a subclass of UIControl)?  The subview has a triangular area of a certain size.  If I remove my finger from within the triangle I want the UIControl superview to trigger its action.  I tried to forward touchesEnd from the subview to the superview with nextResponder but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

To programmatically fire an event on a UIControl, use this method:

```
- (void)sendActionsForControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents
```

for example:

```
- (void)touchUpInside {
    // will need to cast superview to UIControl
    [[self superview] sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

more info on this method [in the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIControl/sendActionsForControlEvents%3a).